# How could I create an outlined bezier object from another object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I am finding this question particular hard to word, so please bear with me. I have a particular vector object that is irregularly shaped (in this case, it is an "r" that I traced with the pen tool), and I want to create another object that is a certain radius out from the original object... Here's an image to illustrate:

[image]

The solid-stroke "R" is the original object, and the dotted-stroke "R" is my desired object. Any way in Illustrator to derive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a ***seperate object*** that you can then do other things with without needing to expand the original, rather than another stroke that is tied to the same object, you can use **Offset Path** ( Object menu > Path > Offset Path ).

[image]

Note how in the example it's adding a new separate object with its own seperate fill.

The new object will usually be grouped with the original - you can either ungroup, or drag the new stuff out from the group in the layers palette, or double-click into isolation mode then cut and paste it out.

Comment: i come back almost a year later and this is the more useful answer... thanks

Answer (score 5):

Add a new stroke via the Appearance Panel.

Highlight the new stroke in the Appearance panel and choose Effect > Path > Offset Path

Tick "preview" and insert a number for the offset you want.

[image]